# Two date pickers show up in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, date

I'm using the following markup to pop up a date picker on a page.

```
<input type="date" id="datepicker"/>

$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z4cNr/) for the fiddle.

Now the problem I'm having is although it works well in Firefox, Chrome shows two date pickers (one from browser and one from JQuery). I can resolve this simply by removing `type="date"` but I'm forced to use `type="date"` because this site should support mobile devices. When I remove the `type="date"` in Android it doesn't show the native date picker and get's messy to select a date.

Comment: @BenR Thank you for pointing out although Modernizr seems to do the trick I would like to know if there is a way we can suppress the default datepicker shown by chrome just in case I wanna get the same Date Picker (JQuery one) on all browsers.

Comment: @Geethanga Set a click handler and return `false` to disable the default component